# What progresses analysis of Alterna Logs?

Tags: splatoon-3

In the campaign mode there are Alterna Logs that have been unlocking over time until they show "analysis complete".
It seems to be linked to campaign progress, but I can't tell what specifically counts for that. (Clearing stages, replaying levels with different weapons, clearing fuzzy spots out of the hub world, etc)

What progresses the analysis of Alterna Logs?

Comment: No source but pretty sure is beating kettles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience, I completed a log for a region once I **completed all distinct kettle levels in that region**, including boss levels.  I did not increase analysis by replaying a level with a different weapon.  There appears to be enough text in each log that it will only be complete when completing all the levels in that region.  It does not matter which order the levels are played in as the log will always be analyzed a couple rows at a time from top to bottom.